# PHP-FPM (PHP 7.0), with mod_fastcgi and Apache 2.2 - is this reliable?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, php-fpm

I'm a relative Linux newbie, so I realize I have enough knowledge to do something dumb.  I was wondering if anyone could comment on this:

On a RHEL 6.2 server with Apache 2.2.  I installed PHP 7.0 along with PHP-FPM, which is listening on a Unix socket.

Here's where the fun started.

Due to my company restricting `wget` access to remote repos, I ended up having to compile and install `mod_fastcgi` from [this source](https://www.pccc.com/downloads/apache/current/) (circa 2007!).  It is version 2.4.6

After several hours of churning, I got it working and have a successful phpinfo() which happily states:

```
Server API  FPM/FastCGI   
php-fpm     active
```

My question is - is this going to be a "good" platform for me to deploy my PHP code to?  The sheer digging I had to do to get to the point where this worked, along with first going down a path of using `mod_fcgid` then switching to the (older?) `mod_fastcgi` -- makes me a little nervous.

Comment: Don't put this on the Internet. It's dangerously out of date.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - just curious, what is bad about it and what would a good alternative be?  Just plain old mod_php?  This is not going on the internet; only on a (heavily firewalled) private internal network...

Comment: The whole system is years out of date, to begin with. Second, I wouldn't build a new project on an old OS. I'd start with RHEL 7 (and mod_fastcgi was [obsoleted](http://serverfault.com/a/629964/126632) some time ago as well).

Comment: Thanks.  I can port the project later, this is only dev and deep inside the company.  I have zero choice on OS...that's what they serve up internally.  Knowing my company they probably hardened RHEL 6 by re-writing half of it...  I guess I just want to know if my config will work reliably enough for code development.

Comment: And they let you run a current version of PHP? Surprise! Have you considered looking for work somewhere a little more sane?

Comment: I had to d/l PHP 7 myself and install it.  I think I screwed up...and could have asked for RHEL 7.  I will see about wiping this server out and re-installing RHEL 7.  Thanks for the pointers!